# Projection query to resource with same name as EntityType

Tags: javascript, breeze

In our project we are performing a projection query on the server. The resource name of the projection query has the same name as an EntityType. When we receive the results Breeze is trying to stuff our results into the EntityType. After stepping through the code I believe this happens in the `visitAndMerge` function.

```
if (mappingContext.query && nodeContext.nodeType === "root" && !meta.entityType) {
        meta.entityType = mappingContext.query._getToEntityType &&
        mappingContext.query._getToEntityType(mappingContext.entityManager.metadataStore);
}
```

The `_getToEntityType` eventually calls `_getFromEntityType` which is matching our resource with our EntityType. Not quite sure if this is a bug or more of a Breeze rule, but we thought we would bring it up because we had a case where we didn't want to match the resource name to the EntityType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing a query Breeze uses a resource name / entity type name map to resolve type information. This map is automatically updated using EntitySet names as resource names when working with an Entity Framework backend. This type information is used in validating and constructing the query url.

You can also update this map directly [See Api Docs - setEntityTypeForResourceName](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_setEntityTypeForResourceName). A single entityType can have any number of resource names associated with it

Once data is returned from a server Breeze tries to extract entityType information according to the following sequence: ( we do need to document this better).

First it examines the json payload returned and uses a *JsonResultsAdapter* to determine the type of any entities returned. This is important when retrieving graphs of entities of more than one type or with queries involving inherited subtypes. You can plug your own *JsonResultsAdapter* in for any query.

If no entity types are resolved in the prior step,  then Breeze will use whatever entityType was specified in any *EntityQuery.toType* method call.

If the previous step did not resolve an entityType and the query is NOT a projection, i.e. uses a select statement, then the map mentioned above is consulting based on the initial resource name specified in the query.

Hope this helps.